# form redirection when clicking commandButton

Tags: visualforce

I have a simple form on that's invoked with a custom button on the Account.  I'm calling with the url

/apex/myPage?id={!someAccntParameter}.

On my production org, this causes the form to appear with the URL

https://emea.salesforce.com/apex/myPage.

On clicking a commandButton to post a form, this causes a redirect (with a method that returns void, no less) to

https://c.eu0.visual.horse.com/apex/myPage.

This causes the form to clear itself upon reload (which I did not want).  Is this some new security I'm encountering with API v 32?

Comment: Do you have a rerender property defined in your command button? If not then the page will reload after you click it.

Comment: Hope visual.horse is a typo otherwise it would be exceptionally weird... But I would expect your first URL to automatically redirect to the second URL when the page is initially rendered (before the button is clicked). Don't know why that isn't happening.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why there's a horse in my URL :)  
But I've fixed this now - just added a rerender property to a panel on the page and it works now just fine.